# Redux: dispatching an action according to cross-reducers state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, reducers

This is my combined reducers:

```
export const element = (state, action) => {
  ...
}

export const elementSelection = (state, action) => {
  ...
}


const holoApp = combineReducers({
  elements,
  elementSelection
})
```

The state of elementSelection holds the current selected element. I want to be able to dispatch an action in the elementsReducer according to the current selected element.

For instance if store.getState().elementSelection.elementType equals "placeholder" this action will be disptached:

```
store.dispatch(replaceElement(...));
```

And otherwise this action will be dispatched:

```
store.dispatch(addElement(...));
```

My only guess is to put this logic in the app class which consists of the store and I wonder whether it is the best practice for dispatching actions according to cross-reducers state.

Answer (score 1):

you can achive that in action creator with redux-thunk

```
const someAction = elem => (dispatch, getState)=>{

   if(getState().elementSelection.elementType == "placeholder" ){
       dispatch(replaceElement(...)); 
   }else{
       dispatch(addElement(...)); 
   }
}
```